# Calculations based on values from 2 tables

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, if-statement, lambda

I am trying to find the farthest point by coordinates. I have 2 data tables:

```
data={'X':[1,1,1,3,4],'Y':[1,2,4,3,5]}
data=pd.DataFrame(data)

points={'ID':['1','2','3','4'],'X':[1,2,4,5],'Y':[3,3,4,1]}
points=pd.DataFrame(points)
```

I would like to determine which point from the "points" table is the farthest one from the coordinates included in the "data" table. The calculation I wish to use is the vector distance as follows.

d = √(x2 −x1)2 +(y2 −y1)2

Based on the example, this is my "data":
[photo in link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHkER.png)
And this is "points" table:
[photo in link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utIrM.png)

I would like to indicate that the **ID 4** in the "points" table is the farthest point (red one in the picture) from the coordinates in the "data" table.
What I've tried:

```
points['DISTANCE']=data.apply(lambda x: (np.sqrt(((x['X']-points['X'])**2)+((x['Y']-points['Y'])**2))).max(), axis=1)
```

Unfortunately the code returns a wrong result, not what I expected. ID 4 should have the most value in DISTANCE column.

| ID | X | Y | DISTANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 4.242641 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 3.605551 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 3.000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | 2.828427 |

I am asking for help in solving this problem.

Comment: `x['X'] - points['X']` are you sure of this? the first term is a single value, the second one is a series...

Comment: I did it because I wanted to calculate the distance between "points" table and the coordinates in the first row of the "data" table. Then repeat this operation for the values in the next row, and so on. Then pick the maximum value. Do you have another idea how to solve it?

Comment: The equation you wrote uses x1 and x2 as single values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
data={'X':[1,1,1,3,4],'Y':[1,2,4,3,5]}
data=pd.DataFrame(data)

points={'ID':['1','2','3','4'],'X':[1,2,4,5],'Y':[3,3,4,1]}
points=pd.DataFrame(points)

def distance(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    return np.sqrt(
        ((x2-x1)**2) + ((y2-y1)**2)
    )
    
results = []
for n, row in points.iterrows():
    id = row.ID
    x1 = row.X
    y1 = row.Y
    for _n, _row in data.iterrows():
        x2 = _row.X
        y2 = _row.Y
        d = distance(x1, x2, y1, y2)
        results.append((d, id))
        print(f'{id} Point({x1},{y1}) vs Data({x2},{y2}) -> {d}')
```

Output:

```
1 Point(1,3) vs Data(1,1) -> 2.0
1 Point(1,3) vs Data(1,2) -> 1.0
1 Point(1,3) vs Data(1,4) -> 1.0
1 Point(1,3) vs Data(3,3) -> 2.0
1 Point(1,3) vs Data(4,5) -> 3.605551275463989
2 Point(2,3) vs Data(1,1) -> 2.23606797749979
2 Point(2,3) vs Data(1,2) -> 1.4142135623730951
2 Point(2,3) vs Data(1,4) -> 1.4142135623730951
2 Point(2,3) vs Data(3,3) -> 1.0
2 Point(2,3) vs Data(4,5) -> 2.8284271247461903
3 Point(4,4) vs Data(1,1) -> 4.242640687119285
3 Point(4,4) vs Data(1,2) -> 3.605551275463989
3 Point(4,4) vs Data(1,4) -> 3.0
3 Point(4,4) vs Data(3,3) -> 1.4142135623730951
3 Point(4,4) vs Data(4,5) -> 1.0
4 Point(5,1) vs Data(1,1) -> 4.0
4 Point(5,1) vs Data(1,2) -> 4.123105625617661
4 Point(5,1) vs Data(1,4) -> 5.0
4 Point(5,1) vs Data(3,3) -> 2.8284271247461903
4 Point(5,1) vs Data(4,5) -> 4.123105625617661
```

To get the most distant:

```
max_distance, id_max_distance = sorted(results)[-1]
print(max_distance) #5.0
print(id_max_distance) #4
```

Comment: Is this the right calculation you are looking for?

Comment: I can apply this solution to my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use scipy.spatial.distance.cdist - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897108/compute-distance-matrix-with-numpy#47899985) for more details.

Then you can use [np.argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to find which is farthest.

HTH.